# How do I find version numbers for Google Chrome offline installers?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I discover version numbers/download URLs for [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) ***offline*** installers? E.g.
for the latest version?

Alternatively what is the ***offline*** installer download URL for the latest version of Google Chrome?

I am able to download an ***offline*** installer for some earlier versions of Google Chrome by knowing the download URLs, e.g.:

> http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/154.36/chrome%5Finstaller.exe

or

> http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/195.21/chrome_installer.exe

(11.1 MB and 10.5 MB respectively)

Is there a list somewhere of the download URLs or the versions numbers (presuming the download URL can be derived from the version number)?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the blog called [Google Chrome Releases](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/) to follow announcements and release notes for the Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

The article
[Official Link to Download Google Chrome Full Standalone Offline Installer](https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/standalonesetup.exe)
contains a summary of known links for
the full offline installer of Google Chrome :

> **New Links**: (always download latest release version)
>
> [Google Chrome Standalone Offline Installer (32-bit)](https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/standalonesetup.exe)
>   [Google Chrome Standalone Offline Installer (64-bit)](https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/standalonesetup64.exe)
>
> **Alternative Links**: (other working download links)
>
> [Google Chrome Offline Installer (32-bit)](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1)
>   [Google Chrome Offline Installer (64-bit)](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1&platform=win64)
>
> **For All User Accounts**: (if you want to install Chrome for all user accounts)
>
> [Google Chrome Offline Installer (32-bit)](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?system=true&standalone=1)
>   [Google Chrome Offline Installer (64-bit)](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?system=true&standalone=1&platform=win64)

**Older versions of Chrome**

For older versions of Chrome, most download addresses don't work any more and just point today
to the latest version, since Google doesn't keep old versions.

The simplest way to test your website with an old chromium based browser, is with
the [SRWare Iron Browser](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php) which is based on Chromium.
This browser is a privacy-conscious version of Google Chrome with several features removed
including auto-update.

Old Iron Browser releases can be downloaded from their [sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/srwareiron.mirror/files/?source=navbar),
where one can find versions ranging today from 20 to 41.

Comment: any chance how to get links for older versions? I'd like to be able to get one to compare changed features/bugs

Comment: @CostinGușă These are not offline installers, but FileHippo [hosts old versions](http://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/history) of Google Chrome upto version 6.0.408.1 Beta. Some of these are standalone installers while others just take you to Google's download page which I believe downloads the latest version anyway since Google doesn't provide old versions of Google Chrome for download. You can however, get old versions [upto 26.0.1410.5 Dev from oldversion.com](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome/) (not all standalone installers)

Comment: @CostinGușă: I have added above information about procuring older Chromium versions via the SRWare Iron Browser downloads.

Comment: @CostinGușă: Forgot your bounty?

Answer (score 0):

This will download the latest version of the offline installer (but does require JavaScript to be enabled in the browser for `google.com`):

> http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1

At the time of writing the file name `chromesetup_195_38.exe` is suggested and the download URL can thus be guessed to be:

> http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/195.38/chrome_installer.exe

This URL can be used without requiring JavaScript (e.g. with [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget).)

I have downloaded this installer and installed. Using icon <Wrench> (popup menu)/About Google Chrome it displays this version number:

> 3.0.195.38

However this is not the latest stable version of Google Chrome. That is version 4.0.249, released on 2010-01-25. Version 3.0 was released on 2009-10-12.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can get the latest version directly from the [Chrome page](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1). You can also get the latest version as well as past versions (all the way back to the first release) from [FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/).

The installers from the Google page pack a Google Update installer and the Chrome installer together. When you run it, it extracts the two and runs them. The FileHippo copy is only the extracted Chrome installer (including the Google digital signature).

As such, the version resource in the properties of the FileHippo installer matches the version of the browser, but the installers from Google have a different one. If you get the one from Google, you can determine the version by using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to open the EXE file, then the file inside that and looking at the filename of the installer. Either way, you can tell a Chrome version by either running it and checking `Wrench->About` or just looking at the version resources of `CHROME.DLL` (for some reason `CHROME.EXE` always has a version of 0.0.0.0).

Comment: By the way, it should be noted that the standalone installer on the Chrome page is only the last stable version; it is not the “latest” version (which is available on FileHippo). When I posted the answer two days ago, the version on the Chrome page was 10.0.648.133 while the version available from FileHippo was 11.0.696.3.

Comment: This might have worked at some point in time. File Hippo files are now useless, unless you are downloading the latest stable version. This is because they don't host the files, they just redirect to Google servers and Google has made sure to pull off any version that's not the latest version.

Comment: @sammyg, that’s a shame. Google is certainly baffling. On the one hand, they retain every version of everything for eternity (e.g., Google Maps now allows you to look at previous satellite photos, not just the latest ones), but on the other hand, they *force* users to update to the latest version of everything whether we like it or not (usually not). Yet another reason to stop using all Google products and services. In the meantime, you could try using Chromium; the last I checked, Google still kept every version of that on their buildbot back to the very first one.