# How to install Google Chrome completely offline and without checking for new version?

Tags: google-chrome, installation

I have downloaded the offline (consumer, i.e. not msi package) installer for Google Chrome. But when I run it, it tries to contact a Google server to check for a newer version. If it finds it, it will download that first, and then install that version. It doesn't use the version that is already there, as part of the EXE file. For me, that defeats the point of having an offline installer. I keep a repository of all the free and purchased software locally, so that I can install them quickly whenever I need to. But as more and more people get access to broadband Internet connections, many developers and companies are pushing for offline installers with new releases. Many software titles, like Google Chrome, are almost exclusively distributed with online installers.

```
File name: ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe
File version: 1.3.21.115
Size: 36.6 MB (38 416 368 bytes)
SHA-1: 2393BAB7F408DC8D30F039FCA5D6B45600A0C4E7
```

How do I install Chrome as is, without automatically checking for and getting a newer version?

Will [Chromium command switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) work with Chrome installer? Is there a switch to disable version check when running the installer?

**Update:**

The "duplicate" question linked to below points out File Hippo as a possible repository where you one can get previous versions of Chrome. They do have a healthy listing of pretty much every single Chrome version ever released on Windows, both beta, dev and stable versions. Unfortunately they don't host the installer files, they only redirect to Google servers for downloads, which only spits out the installers for the latest versions of Chrome. It's not just File Hippo, I also tried downloading an older version of Chrome from CNET Downloads, and they too just redirect you to Google servers for download.

For whatever the reason (security related probably), Google doesn't like anyone to install an older version of Chrome on any system. Apparently not even your common source for downloading an older version of a software, like the CNET Downloads, not even they are allowed to host the Chrome installer files on their own servers. The redirects to Google is probably dictated by Google.

> Google is a dictator!

They don't even allow full standalone offline installers to be installed as is, without checking for newer version. I tried running the installer from cmd with some of the command line switches used for Chromium. I only ended up with errors.

[image: a]

The business oriented msi installer (*GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi*) might have some additional command line options you can use, but I wouldn't know if there is one that disables the check for a newer version. I have yet to find a complete list of switches you can use. The only one I've found so far is `/update` but that only does the opposite thing. So I'll give up here and go back to the trusty Firefox.

Comment: I guess I could unplug the Ethernet cable to force it to use the executable as is, but surely, there must be some other option available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find version numbers for Google Chrome offline installers?](http://superuser.com/questions/116521/how-do-i-find-version-numbers-for-google-chrome-offline-installers)

Comment: I know [where to find](https://support.google.com/installer/answer/126299?hl=en) the offline installers. But even if you download the full blown offline installer of 36 MB, the dumb thing still operates like an online installer and wants to tap into Google servers to see if there is a newer version available. If it finds it, it will download that first, and then install. For testing purposes, this is like it's shooting itself in the leg. If it fails to find a newer version, it will proceed to install from executable.

Comment: "Will Chromium command switches work with Chrome installer?"  What happened when you tried them?

Comment: I haven't tried any of them, because I still don't know if I can use those. Which ones do you suggest I try? There is one called `--check-for-update-interval` could that be it? It says interval... I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Disconnect/disable the network connection on the machine.
- Install the version of Chrome you have the installer for.
- Run it, and [disable it's auto-update](http://www.wintips.org/disable-google-chrome-automatic-update/).
- Exit Chrome.
- Enable networking again.

Comment: Sadly, this is the only workaround.

Comment: Also, it will update anyway because this leaves the update services and tasks running.  In fact, by the time you run it, it will be updating.

Answer (score 5):

Disabling Google's desire to update is actually much more complex than it ever should be.  Steps you must take:

- Install the MSI with the "NOGOOGLEUPDATING" parameter, if possible
- Kill the running update task (which usually starts during the install) and do NOT open Chrome until you have completed the following steps.
- Remove the update folder manually and remove "GoogleUpdate.exe"
- Set both Google Update services "gupdate" and "gupdatem" to "disabled"
- Disable the scheduled tasks for GoogleUpdate (note if you remove them, they will likely get replaced;  disabling will deter the replacement that Google tries to push)
- Set the registry keys to disable updating (or download the Google GPO admin template and set the keys via GPO.)
- Check the additional registry keys under HKLM|Software|Google|Update and remove any "client"-related entries

There is an NSA document that details how to really disable the updating, at https://www.iad.gov/iad/library/ia-guidance/security-configuration/applications/deploying-and-securing-google-chrome-in-a-windows-enterprise.cfm but it does not include the last registry edit that I mention above.

Please note that if you install Chrome and run it before disabling all the places needed to disable updating, it will already be at the new version before you get a chance to do anything.

Also, Google has gone to great lengths to remove all but the latest version from all repositories, so you'd have to find someone who has an older MSI.

Comment: This is a lot of work. But I will check it out, I might learn a thing or two. *Google only officially supports the latest stable channel release of Chrome. The latest stable channel version number for Chrome on Windows can be found at http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/win*

Comment: I agree that it's a lot of work;  it took me a long time to find out how to install Chrome without it updating itself, as Google has taken many steps to make it near-impossible.  But I needed to fix the release for a corporate deployment and so did the research you see reflected in the above. Re. the above comments, the MSI installer parameter is "NOGOOGLEUPDATING" as I mentioned in my answer.  There's no shortcut for this;  miss any steps and you'll find yourself on the new version by the time you open it the first time (or find it updating right then.)

Comment: If you kill the running update task (which usually starts during the install), the msiexec install will FAIL.

Comment: Note that you just need to kill the task immediately after installing, before running Chrome.

Comment: The NSA Link became dead, I updated it with an IAD.gov link. Also, this PDF has the registry key OP mentioned: [Security Configuration Guide for Browser Updates](https://www.iad.gov/iad/library/ia-guidance/security-configuration/applications/security-configuration-guide-for-browser-updates.cfm)

Comment: Really late to see this (by half a year) but @PeterFnet thank you for posting the updated link;  it's more comprehensive & revealing than Google's documentation for this issue.

Comment: The IAD link is broken now...